# String reference

Tags: c#, string, reference

If `a` and `b` are both references to the same object why doesn't value of `a` change when we change value of `b` in *part3*. And if I assume that (as in *part3*) that `b` is dereferenced when I pass it a new literal string ,why doesn't it also dereference in *part2* when I pass `"foo"` litaral string (`ReferenceEquals` returns `true`).

```
//part1
string a = "foo";
string b = a;
System.Console.WriteLine("\na = {0}\nb = {1}", a, b); //a=foo b=foo
System.Console.WriteLine("a == b : {0}", a == b);//True
System.Console.WriteLine("ReferenceEquals(a, b): {0}", ReferenceEquals(a, b));//True

//part2
b = "foo";
System.Console.WriteLine("\na = {0}\nb = {1}", a, b);//a=foo b=foo
System.Console.WriteLine("a == b : {0}", a == b);//True
System.Console.WriteLine("ReferenceEquals(a, b): {0}", ReferenceEquals(a, b));//True

//part3
b = "bar";
System.Console.WriteLine("\na = {0}\nb = {1}", a, b);//a=foo b=bar
System.Console.WriteLine("a == b : {0}", a == b);//False
System.Console.WriteLine("ReferenceEquals(a, b): {0}", ReferenceEquals(a, b));//False
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` and `b` both refer to the same object.
However, you're changing `b`, not the object.

`String` objects are immutable and cannot be changed.

When you write `b = "foo"`, you're changing `b` to refer to a different `String` instance.

---

However, string literals are [*interned*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx), so writing `"foo"` will always give the same `String` instance.

You can get two different `String` instances with the same value by calling [`String.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.copy.aspx):

```
string a = "foo";
string b = "foo";
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(a, b));    //True

b = String.Copy("foo");
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(a, b));    //False
```

Comment: Surely your penultimate and last paragraphs are contracting each other... Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Misunderstanding. if you write "foo" to code, all of them would have the same reference. String.Copy(anything) will create unique string, which has different reference than any other.

Answer (score 3):

If you change something , like `a = "newstring";` it means, that 'a' points to *new reference*.

Strings are *immutable* -> you *cannot* change string itself (`a[0] = 'b';`).

In part2, when you assign some constant used previously, the reference to the old one is used. This is called 'Interning'.

If you did `b = "fo" + "o";`, the references wouldn't be equal (in this example they would, because compiler optimizes this, but if the string is created other way than directly used, references are the same).

```
var a = "foo";
var b = "fo";
b = b + "o";
// in this point, the references AREN'T equal.
b = string.Intern(b);
// in this point, the references ARE equal.
```

Answer (score 1):

"Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it appear as if you can do this."

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

a and b are both references to the same thing in part 1

In part 2 the references remain the same because the compiler has worked out in advance you are just reusing the same string literal (a little memory optimisation) and because strings are immutable it knows it is safe to make that optimisation.

In part 3 you are changing the reference to b only. a remains a reference to "foo" as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

a and b both refer to the same object. How can a change, if you are assigning 'a' to 'b' and then changing the value of 'b'